# Can we override the org.springframework.core.JdkVersion and have this class loaded instead of the default that comes with Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to override the default behavior of a class that comes from external libraries like Spring and have the classloader load the custom implementation instead of the default one.

We are seeing below error , as our Spring is 2.5.6, and JDK 8. Due to timelines, we are not looking at upgrading Spring, and instead seeing if we can hack **org.springframework.core.JdkVersion.**

```
"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher"
```

The default implementation of JdkVersion in Spring 2.5.6, supports 1.5,1.6 and 1.7 only.

We also tried other option to override java.version system property.
Option A ) We passed -Djava.version=1.7.0 while starting tomcat instance , but still it is returning 1.8.0.
Option B) We programatically set the java version in ContextListener class, but the exception is thrown even before web context is created.

So, the option we are thinking is to write custom JdkVersion, and somehow have it loaded instead of the one that comes with Spring context library.

Is this option even possible ? or any other approaches that can tried, without upgrading the spring and not adding the entire Spring library to source and build it.

Thanks

The other option we thought is

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing `JdkVersion`?

Comment: The point is that is that this is an **internal** class that Spring uses to determine what the platform is.  Changing the class to recognize Java 8 is not going to magically let Spring 2.5.6 use Java 8 features or deal with Java 8 specific incompatibilities.   Read the official response to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16518.  If you need to run on Java 8, you should upgrade to a later version of Spring.

Comment: Hello @StephenC, we are not particularly using any Java 8 features in our application.  But I understand that Spring 2.5.6 may not work and may have runtime issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, replacing `JdkVersion` with a custom version *could* work.  If you are going to do that, the clean way would be to download the relevant Spring source code, make the change, build it, and use the resulting artifacts instead of the standard ones.

I am not going to say that it *will* work:

1. The Spring guys don't recommend it, and clearly don't intend to support it.  See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/16518.
2. You haven't actually explained clearly what you are trying to achieve by doing this.  So I / we don't understand what "will it work?" actually means.

IMO, a better idea would be to upgrade your application's Spring dependencies.  Spring 2.5.6 is very old, and way beyond "end of life".  Furthermore, I am pretty sure that this hack you are proposing won't work when you need to upgrade to Java 11.

---

Note the `-D` approach won't work.  You can't override that property that way.  The JVM will override your override.  And setting the property programmatically ... early enough ... would be difficult.